# Admob - How to detect horizontal orientation and hide admob?

Tags: android, admob, screen-orientation

I am new to programming in Java and Android. I got admob to work at the most basic level, and whenever the device is at the landscape orientation, admob tends to popup and occupy a huge potion of the screen.

What is the best way to detect the orientation and hide the ads from displaying if it is in horizontal orientation? Is it necessary to put the admob application in a thread to check for change in orientation and hide/unhide it?

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can you just not include it in your layout XML file for landscape?  You can have a landscape version of your layout by including "-land" at the end of the layout folder name.  For example:

```
/res/
  /layout/
    /main.xml
  /layout-land/
    /main.xml
```

If main.xml is the layout you have loading for an activity, the OS will automatically load the one in the layout-land folder for when the phone is a landscape orientation.  Therefore in that XML file you can re-adjust the admob ad in the layout or remove it completely (if it is a layout object? I've never user admob).